# Google Sign In ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'errorMessage

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to solve the problem of logging in to Google. The application registers the account normally, and it will appear to me that a user has registered, but the main page does not open automatically, but when the application is completely closed and reopened, it works

E/flutter ( 5938): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'errorMessage'
E/flutter ( 5938): #0      _TypeError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:105:68)

Comment: please show your logging in to Google code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Beginning extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BeginningState createState() => _BeginningState();
}

class _BeginningState extends State<Beginning> {
  final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool isLogged = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance
        .authStateChanges()
        .listen((User? user) {
      if (user == null) {
        print('User is currently signed out!');
        setState(() {
          isLogged = false;
        });

      } else {
        print('User is signed in!');
        setState(() {
          isLogged = true;
        });

      }

    });
    super.initState();
  }
  
  Stream<User?>authStatus(){
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: Provider.of<AuthService>(context,listen: false).authStatus(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot){
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active){
            return snapshot.data != null ? HomeView() : IntroView();
          }
          else{
            return SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        }
    );
  }
}
```

You can open a page called beginning.dart and copy the above code. In the main.dart page, you can specify the path as Beginning(). When it is done in this way, you can direct it to your homepage, which I define as HomeView() when the user logs in, and to your user introduction page, which I define as IntroView(), otherwise.